# fulfillment code error Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, fulfillment, voximplant

I am developing a voice assistant through dialogflow, google calendar and voximplant.
I have a problem in the fulfillment code because, I don't know why, but I constantly get this error in the DIAGNOSTIC INFO, as well as a series of errors on the console log. Would anyone know how to give me a hand?

I will post the code below:

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const {google} = require('googleapis');
 const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
 
 // Enter your calendar ID below and service account JSON below
const calendarId = 'c_d86ppgn4qqpmfpq1cjd2higja8@group.calendar.google.com'; 
const serviceAccount = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "italians-do-it-better",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxxxxxxxx@italians-do-it-better.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/appointmentscheduler%40italians-do-it-better.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
};

 const serviceAccountAuth = new google.auth.JWT({
   email: serviceAccount.client_email,
   key: serviceAccount.private_key,
   scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
 });
 
 const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
 process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
 const timeZone = 'Europe/Kaliningrad';
 const timeZoneOffset = '+02:00';
 
 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   const agent = new WebhookClient({request, response});
   console.log("Parameters", agent.parameters);
   const appointment_type = "Default";
         //agent.parameters.AppointmentType;
   
   function makeAppointment (agent) {
     // Calculate appointment start and end datetimes (end = +1hr from start)
     console.log("Parameters", agent.parameters.date);
     
     //Variabili più calcolo orario
     const guests = agent.parameters.guests;
     const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0]  + 'T' +  agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('+')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
     const dateTimeEnd = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart).setHours(dateTimeStart.getHours() + 1));
     console.log("date start ", dateTimeStart, " date end ", dateTimeEnd);
     
     const date = new Date(agent.parameters.date);
     const bookingDate = new Date(date);
     
     const phonenumber = agent.parameters.phonenumber;
     let name = agent.parameters.name;
     const email = agent.parameters.email;
     var phone = phonenumber.toString().length;
     const now = new Date();
     
     const appointmentTimeString = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString( 'en-US', {timeZone:'Europe/Kaliningrad'});
     
     if (guests < 1){
       agent.add(`You need to reserve a table for at least one person. Please try remaking the reservation!`);
     } 
     else if (guests > 100){
       agent.add(`You can't make a reservation for more than 100 guests. Please try remaking the reservation!`);
     }else if (dateTimeStart < now){
       agent.add(`You can't make a reservation in the past. Please try remaking the reservation.`);
      } 
     else if (bookingDate.getFullYear() > now.getFullYear()) {
       agent.add(`You can't make a reservation for ${bookingDate.getFullYear()} yet. Please choose a date in ${now.getFullYear()}.`);
     }
     else if (phone != 10) {
       agent.add(`Your phone number has to be atleast 10 digits. Please try remaking the reservation!`);
     } else {     
     console.log("appointmentTimeString: ", appointmentTimeString);
     
     // Check the availibility of the time, and make an appointment if there is time on the calendar
     return createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, guests, name, phonenumber, email, appointment_type).then(() => {
       agent.add(`Ok, let me see if we can fit you in. ${appointmentTimeString} is fine!.`);
     }).catch(() => {
       agent.add(`I'm sorry, there are no slots available for ${appointmentTimeString}.`);
     });
   }  
   let intentMap = new Map();
   intentMap.set('collectIncorrectValues', makeAppointment);
   intentMap.set('ScheduleAppointment.yes', makeAppointment);
   agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
   }});
 
 function createCalendarEvent (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, guests, name, phonenumber, email, appointment_type) {
   const appointmentTimeString = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString( 'en-US', {timeZone:'Europe/Kaliningrad'});
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     calendar.events.list({
       auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
       calendarId: calendarId,
       timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
       timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
     }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
       // Check if there is a event already on the Calendar
       if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
         reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
       } else {
         // Create event for the requested time period
         calendar.events.insert({ auth: serviceAccountAuth,
           calendarId: calendarId,
           resource: {summary: 'Appointment: '+ appointment_type +' Appointment ', description: appointmentTimeString +',\n Name: ' + name + ',\n Guests: '+ guests + ',\n Phonenumber: ' + phonenumber + ',\n Email: ' +email,
             start: {dateTime: dateTimeStart},
             end: {dateTime: dateTimeEnd}}
         }, (err, event) => {
           err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
                 }
         );
       }
     });
   });
 }
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

**Console log error:**

[image: Console log]
[image: Console log]
[image: Console log]
[image: Console log]

**Dialogflow error:**
[image: Dialogflow error]
[image: Dialogflow error]

**Console log error:**

```
{
  "textPayload": "Error: No handler for requested intent\n    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/workspace/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:317:29)\n    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/workspace/index.js:89:10)\n    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)\n    at process.nextTick (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:100:17)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)",
  "insertId": "000000-9adc6f24-bfa5-469b-ae82-5f4124522534",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "italians-do-it-better"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-07-13T08:31:30.209Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "v9ps952et2kk"
  },
  "logName": "projects/italians-do-it-better/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/italians-do-it-better/traces/f4d789b9c84aaf5bb311c9332f125ca8",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-07-13T08:31:30.716907289Z"
}
```

Comment: Please don't include your service account credentials on your post moving forward, as it can be used to access your GCP resources. Also can show the specific error log as well and post the full stack trace in your question?

Comment: Please show the errors only and if possible, copy the text from the logging instead of images. You can use this query in your logging to show the errors `resource.type="cloud_function" resource.labels.function_name="dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment" severity="ERROR"`. When the errors are shown, expand the log and copy the error and paste it in your question.

Comment: Based from the error, it cannot match any intent that you are mapping. Can you check `intentMap.set('collectIncorrectValues', makeAppointment)` and `intentMap.set('ScheduleAppointment.yes', makeAppointment);` if they are mapped to the correct intent? Please make sure that the created intents are spelled correctly.

Comment: Also you might have a problem maintaining your code moving forward since you are associating two intents to a single function. I suggest to create a separate function per intent.